# Flex Mobile - make a scrollable view

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex-mobile

In a Flex Mobile app i have a view that contain a "header" which is a carousel of images and a 2 column list  (point 1 on attached image). The list is scrollable and works great but when scrolling the header remains fixed.  What is the best approach in order to scroll the whole view. I want the header to move and the list to show new elements on full screen.

Here is a image that may help:

[image: example]

Following your answers i end up with this code

```
<s:Scroller id="scroler" left="0" right="0" top="0" >
<s:Group id="container" left="0" right="0" top="0">                                             
<components:restaurantHeader id="header" />
<s:DataGroup dataProvider="{DataModel.instance.listaCategoriiRestaurante}" 
top="260" left="0" right="0"  width="100%" 
itemRenderer="itemRenderers.categoriiRestaurantRender">
<s:layout>
    <s:TileLayout columnWidth="200" rowAlign="justifyUsingHeight" orientation="rows" clipAndEnableScrolling="false" columnAlign="justifyUsingGap" >     
    </s:TileLayout>
</s:layout>     
</s:DataGroup>  
</s:Group>  
</s:Scroller>
```

But now it seems i cannot make the data group list to be a 2 column one. the datagrop list expands on horizontal and not vertical and i end up with 3-4 columns and not extra rows.

Can you tell me how to make the datagroup list stay on 2 columns and expand vertical adding extra rows and not columns.

Thanks again

Comment: I would imagine putting all the view's children in a scroller.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your header and list with a scroller. That would make the list scrolling obsolete though, so you could replace the list component with a DataGroup.